# PHP mysqli is this the easiest way?

Tags: php, optimization, mysqli

The code snippet is meant to return the minimum and maximum id from each round in this table [image] I'm just wondering if there is a less clunky way of doing this.

```
$query = "SELECT round FROM $tablename";
$rounds = Array();
if ($result = $Login->mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $rounds[] = $row['round'];
    }
}
$rounds = array_unique($rounds);
$rounds = array_values($rounds);
$roundBound = Array();
foreach ($rounds as $roundNum) {
    $query = "SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM $tablename WHERE round = $roundNum;";
    $result = $Login->mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    $roundBound[] = $row[0];
    $roundBound[] = $row[1];
}
```

hurr...

Changed to,

```
$query = "SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM $tablename GROUP BY round";
    if($result = $Login->mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $roundBound[] = $row[0];
            $roundBound[] = $row[1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose I don't need the array_values call as I'm doing it through a foreach...

Comment: It was a toss up between sagi and  Marc. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing this in a single query:

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM $tablename GROUP BY round
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be more efficient to run a single query and use a `WHERE round IN (....)` clause:

```
$round_clause = implode(',', $rounds);

$query = "SELECT round, MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM $tablename WHERE round IN ($round_clause) GROUP BY round";
```

As a general rule, doing a single query that returns a "large" number of rows is going to be more efficient than doing a series of smaller/single queries that only return few or one rows at a time. You only scan the indexes once, you only have to retrieve the data once.

Answer (score 1):

use `group by`

using query in foreach is the worst practice I ever seen

```
SELECT Min(id), Max(id) FROM $tablename GROUP BY round
```

Comment: I was having a foreach love child moment, I'm sure you've been there. :P